# User's default shell does not affect sourced files on login

Tags: gnome, 18.04, login, session

Running Ubuntu 18.04.

I changed my login shell to zsh using the command:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh username
```

I figured this would mean that `.zprofile` should be sourced not `.profile`, however that is not the case. Upon login, I get a warning about **session not being setup correctly** because some command inside my `.profile` is not found.

*I can't get the full message because it seems to appear before the DM has finished, so copying the message does not work, nor can I take a screenshot*.

How can I fix this? Am I wrong to assume that `.zprofile` is sourced upon login or is it always `.profile` regardless of user's login shell preference?

---

In my `/etc/passwd`, I also see this entry:

```
username:x:1000:1000:Username,,,:/home/username:/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Check the man pages for zsh on your system, also check http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html for zsh details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to restart my machine.

After the restart, `.profile` was no longer sourced.

I tested this by typing some nonsense into the `.profile` and after logging out and back in, I did not get any errors.